# How do I use str_replace with DomDocument

Tags: php, html, web-scraping, domdocument

I am using DomDocument to pull content from a specific div on a page.

I would then like to replace all instances of links with a path equal to http://example.com/test/ with http://example.com/test.php.

```
$url = "http://pugetsoundbasketball.com/stackoverflow_sample.php";
$doc = new DomDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$doc->loadHtml(file_get_contents($url));
$div = $doc->getElementById('upcoming_league_dates');
foreach ($div->getElementsByTagName('a') as $item) {
    $item->setAttribute('href', 'http://example.com/test.php');
}
echo $doc->saveHTML($div);
```

As you can see in the example above, `str_replace causes` problems after I target the upcoming_league_dates div with `getElementById`. I understand this but unfortunately I don't know where to go from here!

I've tried several different ways including executing the `str_replace` above the `getElementById` function (I figured I could replace the strings first and then target the specific div), with no luck.

What am I missing here?

EDIT: UPDATED CODE TO SHOW WORKING SOLUTION

Comment: Looks like that webpage has lots of duplicated IDs. HTML parsers are going to hate that!

Comment: Also, this got to a **TL;DR** point for me. Please provide some example HTML that isn't so long as that.

Comment: @scrowler I updated the code to pull a simple page with text.. I am not sure if thats what youre asking

Comment: Better - but now your file doesn't have an element with ID upcoming_league_dates. To give a reproducible example you should provide the smallest possible block of code for someone to reproduce your problem. E.g. a div with that id, filled with either links that you want to replace or a bunch of text like you've given.

Comment: @scrowler Sorry I added the id before you finished your comment I believe. And I appreciate the input.. I am learning more and more how to post on StackOverflow each day.

Comment: getElementById() returns a DOMElement which is an object and not a string. I think you should read the DOMDocument documentation because you are not using the DOMDocument API correctly.

Comment: @MagentaCuda Thank you for your reply. I noted in the original post that I am aware it is the incorrect use.. but I dont know what the correct use is

Comment: A DOMElement can be manipulated by statements like $element->setAttribute("href", ...). If you read the documentation you will see that it is not a simple string manipulation API but an object with methods for manipulating attributes. I.e a DOMElement is not a string but an object with an API.

Comment: @MagentaCuda Thank you! Helped turn a light bulb on and I came up with a solution.. See updated code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just use `str_replace` on that node. You need to access it properly first. Thru the `DOMElement` class you can use the method `->setAttribute()` and make the replacement.

Example:

```
$url = "http://pugetsoundbasketball.com/stackoverflow_sample.php";
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$dom->loadHTMLFile($url);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom); // use xpath
$needle = 'http://example.com/test/';
$replacement = 'http://example.com/test.php';
// target the link
$links = $xpath->query("//div[@id='upcoming_league_dates']/a[contains(@href, '$needle')]");
foreach($links as $anchor) {
    // replacement of those href values
    $anchor->setAttribute('href', $replacement);
}

echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Update: After your revision, your code is now working anyway. This is just to answer your logic replacement (ala str_replace search/replace) on your previous question.

Comment: Thanks for the solution @Ghost! Your solution works great for when there are multiple links with different paths and I need to change a few specifically. I will use it in the future. Fortunately all the links on the page in question had the same paths so I was able to use a more general solution.

Comment: @Kevin - How would you replace a value or groups of value. For example if I need to replace `class1` in `<a class="class1 class2 class3">link</a>` with `class-abc`.  The remaining classes be different .

Comment: @Motivated you could still use this way but classes could hold multiple values delimited by a space, so `explode` it first, the exploded string would be your haystack, the needle would the `class1`, then simply use `array_search`, get the index and replace it with your desired value, then glue them all again using `implode`, finally `setAttribute` them again to apply the changes